# Android Studio 2.3 Error converting bytecode to dex

Tags: android, android-studio

**Problem:** I had a problem in installing my apk to my devices having below errors

**Solutions made:**

- Build > Clean Project and then Build > Rebuild Project
- Restarted Android Studio
- Inserted this code to my build gradle and error not solve

  ```
  android {
      dexOptions {
      incremental = true;
      preDexLibraries = false
      javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
      } 
  }
  ```
- Checked my firebase versions under my build.gradle file which are the same

**Devices Tested:**

- Samsung GT-I9505
- Samsung SM-T211

**My Build Gradle**

[image: Build Gradle]

**Error Log:**

[image: Error Log Description]

Hoping for your utmost consideration. Cheers. Thank You.

Comment: did you tried by enabling multidex ?

Comment: @VivekMishra haven't checked it but ill be checking multidex if it solves it.

Comment: Please post build.gradle and errors as text, not screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

This is a build path issue.

Make sure your bin folder is not included in your build path.

Right click on your project -> go to properties -> Build Path.

Make sure that Honeycomb library is in your libs/ folder and not in your source folder.

Include the libraries in libs/ individually in the build path.
    BTW, you may want to bring in the android-support-v4 library to get Ice Cream Sandwich support instead of the Honeycomb support library.